# Php:Regex-How to extract multiple portions of match and store it in an array?

Tags: php, regex

I have a page with the following code:-

```
<ul class="food">
<li>
<i>Bread and Butter</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Cheese</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Milk</i>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="fruits">
<li>
<i>Apple</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Mango</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Strawberry</i>
</li>
</ul>
```

There are two unordered lists, and I want the contents which is between the italic tag, in an array per every unordered list. For example, Apple, Mango and Strawberry, which are the contents of second unordered list should be stored in one array ,say array[1], and the contents of other unordered list should be stored in array[0].
Also the number of items in any of the unordered list is variable or not known beforehand, which is another problem.
The regex I tried was

```
<ul class=".*">\s(?:<li>\s<i>(.*)<\/i>\s<\/li>)+<\/ul>
```

Apart from that regex, I tried many other the whole day, but no success. I am new to regex and php and do not have much idea. Can someone help me with this? 
EDIT: I am allowed only to use regex to get content. Parsing is not allowed

Comment: Don't regex HTML, use a parser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: I am not allowed to parse. Only regex is allowed.

Comment: You'll need to pull each `ul` then iterate over each `li`. See `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split The full String By:

```
/<ul.*?>/m
```

Then iterate over the splits and apply th following regex to capture italics value"

```
/<i>(.*?)<\/i>/m
```

[Run it here](http://ideone.com/tvbVpt)

Src:

```
<?php

$re = '/<ul.*?>/m';
$re1 = '/<i>(.*?)<\/i>/m';
$str = '<ul class="food">
<li>
<i>Bread and Butter</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Cheese</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Milk</i>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="fruits">
<li>
<i>Apple</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Mango</i>
</li>
<li>
<i>Strawberry</i>
</li>
</ul>';

$list=preg_split($re,$str);
for($i=1;$i<count($list);$i++)
{
    preg_match_all($re1, $list[$i], $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
?>
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bread and Butter
    [1] => Cheese
    [2] => Milk
)
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Mango
    [2] => Strawberry
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That was precisely what I wanted.